# Snowball data using jquery deferred

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering what the nicest way of doing this is:

I've got two ajax requests the second request requires the results of the first.

I was trying to find a nice way of getting both results into the `doSomethingWithBothResults` function.

```
var getValue1 = function(){ return $.getJSON('/getVal1'); }
var getValue2 = function(result){ return $.getJSON('/getVal2'+ result.data); }
var doSomethingWithBothResults = function(result1, result2) { alert('r1:' + result1.data +   'r2:' + result2.data); }; 

getValue1.pipe(getValue2).then(doSomethingWithBothResults);
```

So obviously I only get the results from the second call in `doSomethingWithBothResults`. Is there any way of rewriting this nicely to get both results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below shows how you can use a *third* deferred object which is only `resolved` once both queries are complete, and which is passed the result of *both*.

```
var d = $.Deferred();

$.ajax(...).done(function(data1) {
    // use data1 to initiate the second request
    ...

    $.ajax(...).done(function(data2) {
        d.resolve(data1, data2);
    }).fail(d.reject);

}).fail(d.reject);

d.done(function(data1, data2) {
    // do something with both
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply define the second function as the `success` function for the first [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

However, wouldn't it be simpler to put all that data into a single file on the server?  Fewer calls mean faster and cleaner code (usually).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ztH6L/1/

```
var chain = function (opt1, opt2, cb) {
    var r1, r2;
    $.ajax(opt1)
        .done(function (r) { r1 = r;  })
        .pipe(function (r) { opt2.data = {json: JSON.stringify({"v": r})}; return $.ajax(opt2);})
        .done(function (r) { r2 = r;})
        .pipe(function() {cb(r1, r2);});
};

var opt1 = {
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {json: JSON.stringify({"v": 1})},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
};


var opt2 = {
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
};

chain(opt1, opt2, function(r1, r2) {console.log(r1); console.log(r2);});
```

Sorry about getting the requirements wrong, guess didn't read it properly.

Btw, I like @Alnitak's answer better, though mine also works :)

Comment: That's almost what I'm after, the only problem is the second call relies on a value returned by the first call so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the functionality in the controller you post the ajax call too. That is a much cleaner way, and better practise.